# devstack/stackrc:833 Could not determine host ip address. See local.conf for suggestions on setting HOST_IP

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-swift, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

I tried installing openstack in Ubuntu/Virtualbox, but when i give the command ./stack.sh, i get this error : devstack/stackrc:833 Could not determine host ip address.  See local.conf for suggestions on setting HOST_IP. I already changed the HOST_IP to the Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network IPv4 Address using the command : gedit local.conf . Can somebody help me detect the problem please ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add `local.conf` do your question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you solve this? I encountered this today, and I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/neutron/+bug/1693689

**I'm not so sure if this method correct**, but after the method below I can install devstack ussuri.
The default IP of the VM on Virtualbox is 10.0.2.15, and the IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE in /opt/stack/devstack/stackrc is: 10.0.0.0/22.

try to modify /opt/stack/devstack/stackrc

change IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE=${IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE:-10.0.0.0/22}

into IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE=${IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE:-10.1.0.0/22}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

try to check if you missed this  **[[local|localrc]]**

you should add it as in documentation:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWOR
```